# Error 415 on angular although the headers are up

Tags: django, angular

I'm getting error 415 on angular api request but http header are set:

login.service.ts:

```
var httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
return this.httpClient.post<any>(requestUrl, params, { headers: httpHeaders })
```

As backend i used django rest framework
Any idea ?
Thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpHeaders` class is immutable in Angular so now you did not really set any headers. You need to assign the result of `set` operation to you variable.

```js
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// depending on the server settings might also be needed 
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
return this.httpClient.post<any>(requestUrl, params, { headers: httpHeaders })
```